# what should be the ffmpeg command line for watermarking in batch on linux server?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I apply watermark on single video via this command line;

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay" output.mp4
```

what should be the code line for batch on linux server using php?

Comment: im applying watermark via php using ffmpeg on a single video, i wish like we do on local machine to convert video via ffmpeg in batch

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: what have you tried so far to convert video via ffmpeg in batch?